# Firebase_ui_auth SignInPage's EmailAuthProvider displays verbose message in release version of the app. How can I display human readable messages?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

This is my implementation. I get really messy error messages.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

How can I handle the error messages to be cleaner or catch them and provide my own?

```dart
class AuthGateUI extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGateUI({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SignInScreen(
            providers: [
              EmailAuthProvider(),
              GoogleProvider(
                clientId: 'XXX',
                scopes: ['email', 'profile'],
                iOSPreferPlist: true,
              ),
            ],
            footerBuilder: (context, action) => _AuthFooter(),
          );
        }
        return const CustomizeUI(userFirstTime: true);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tired a couple of things like checking if snapshot has error but that does not work

Comment: "I get really messy error messages." I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you edit your question to show the result you get, and the result you expected/want to get?

Comment: Added a screenshot @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your error message, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: I know the source of the error message, I am not asking why I have that error message. I am asking why does firebase-ui-auth displays a verbose error message on user interface rather than a human readable one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.